# How to initiate a public method in Main?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Started learning C# today, but can't get my head around how to call functions/methods in Main.

If I were to have a few methods like the one i have created, and have them all in this file for the benefit of just having to write in one file, I would very much like to call them one by one, just to try them out.

So if I were to call, or initiate this DisplayMessage() within Main, how could I do that?

Since I am as green as it gets, I am also wondering if this would be considered bad practice? Do you always want to have your different classes, and/or functions in seperate files?

Here is what I have managed to produce/learn so far today:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace FirstProgram
{
   class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Call DisplayMessage() here?
        }

        public void DisplayMessage()
        {
            string str1;
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first name:");
            str1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", str1);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Would be thankful if someone would help me (and hopefully others, with somewhat poor programming backround, like my self) out.

Comment: `new Program().DisplayMessage();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't call a non-static method from a static method.  You need to either make the method static, or create an instance.

To make it static, use:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DisplayMessage();
}

public static void DisplayMessage()
{
    string str1;
    // ...
```

Otherwise, you can create an instance, and call the method on the instance:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var program = new Program();
    program.DisplayMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, you can keep `DisplayMessage()` in there for testing it out.

`Main` is a static method, so you have to call other static methods (make `DisplayMessage` static), or you can instantiate the class that the non-static method is in:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program p = new Program();
    p.DisplayMessage();
}
```

In the future, it'll make things simpler (and easier to test) if you keep them in different appropriately-named classes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the method `static`.

Since `Main` is `static`, you can only access other `static` members/methods from it.

So changing your function signature to this:

```
public static void DisplayMessage()
```

Will work.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix would be to make `DisplayMessage()` static:

```
public static void DisplayMessage()
....
```

`static` means that you don't have to create an instance of `Program` to use it, and your `Main` method is static, so you don't have an instance of `Program`.

The other way would be to create an instance of `Program`:

```
Program program = new Program();
program.DisplayMessage();
```

Comment: Why do "you need a constructor to create an instance" ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead You don't in this case, early morning brainfart.

Comment: Indeed. Btw, greetings fellow Victorian :)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead So you would have noticed my small lie that it isn't actually that early any more :)

Comment: I'm still only at coffee #1 for the morning.. so 8.45am is still early in my books.